# Why database gets deleted when an apk has been reinstalled?

Tags: android, database, apk

I have a problem related to the app that I developed which runs on honeycomb. When I reinstall the apk its database gets deleted. There did not used to be this almost 1 week ago. Why this is happening now? What can cause db to be deleted and how to prevent it?

Comment: Look at my edited answer, with links..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, If your database stored in application's internal storage `/data/data/<package_name>/databases/` then when **your application un-installed from device, all directories with your application package are removed from the device this cause your database removed**.

To prevent put your **database copy** in application's `/asset` directory so whenever your application first time runt it copy the database from asset to internal storage path. And you can access it whenever application re-installed, also you can put your database in `/sdcard` but user can also delete it..

**EDIT:** [Using your own SQLite database in Android applications](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) and [How to ship an Android application with a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database)

Thanks...

Comment: firstly thank you for your comment, so how do I do this? Easy thing to do?

Answer (score 0):

i guess it about checking existing database in your code. but i'm not sure exactly, it can occur from many causes. Just give an idea.